# PostgreSQL full-text search retrival from id gap

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, full-text-search

I have a full-text search column on one of my tables in PostgreSQL 9.3 implemented based on [this](http://dlo.me/archives/2014/09/01/postgresql-fts/) tutorial (without the South part). 

There is a postgres function where I

```
SELECT concat_ws(' ', a."my_column1") INTO c1;
SELECT concat_ws(' ', a."my_column2") INTO c2;
RETURN setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.simple', c1), 'C') ||
       setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', c2), 'D');
```

This is being written into a column called *fts_document* in the same table. I have INSERT and UPDATE triggers on this table and a trigger function as in the tutorial.

Everything has worked fine at some point.

After a dump from another db with identical structure and a restore to an empty db I got my table with a gap of the field `id` from 7306 to 21431. The main problem is that now the full-text-search retrieves documents only from this missing id range and the *my_column1* and *my_column2* values are very valid ones. I have deleted the index on *fts_document* column and rebuilt it, but no result.

Where does postgres retrieve these weird ("not existing") rows from? How can I fix the search to retrieve also the existing rows and postgres to show the missing docs?

Answer (score 0):

Found my stupid mistake...
instead of running the query as `my_table.objects.raw(sql_query)` I was creating a connection to another db with

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='wrong_db' user='my_user' password='my_password'")
cur = conn.cursor() 
cur.execute(sql_query)
```

so lesson learnt... use the Django built-in capabilities to eliminate the possibility of a connection to a wrong db.

The coincidence that I was getting `id`s from my gap range was caused by the fact that at some point I had tried to import (unsuccessfully) the entries from `wrong_db` to my db and this created the gap in `id`s.